# Nondegenerate points - Inclusion is a cofibration

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X$ be a locally Euclidean metric space and $x\in X$. Then the inclusion $x\to X$ is a cofibration.

**My attempt:**

I'm using the following result from Bredon: [image]

Let $U\subset X$ be a nbhd of $x$ such that there is a homeomorphism $f:U\to B_1(0)\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $f(x)=0$.

Define the map $$\tilde{\phi}:B_1(0)\to I, \quad y\mapsto \|y\|$$

and the distance map $\phi:X\to I$ to be $\tilde{\phi} \circ f$ on $U$ and $1$ on $X\setminus U$.

Then conditions $(1)$ and $(2)$ of the theorem are satisfied.

Condition $(3)$ is also satisfied: $0$ is a strong deformation retract of $B_1(0)$ and hence $x$ is a strong deformation retract of $U$.

Is this proof correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be a problem with continuity at $\partial U$. But you can do the following:
Let $f:U\to B_2(0)$ be a homeomorphism to the open ball with radius $2$. Let $g:B_2(0)\to I$ be the function $y\mapsto||y||$. Then the restriction of $gf$ is a continuous map $f^{-1}(D_1(0))\to I$ on the preimage of the closed unit ball, which is compact and thus closed, and the constant map to $1$ on the closed set $X\setminus f^{-1}(B_1(0))$ can be glued to this restriction to give a continuous map to $I$ on the entire space $X$.

Comment: Ok, i see. thanks for furnishing that.